# CSS Changes not reflected on associated state change in React with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to make a section where some of the sections get disabled when a particular button is clicked, the way I am doing it is by creating two different CSS properties like so:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    disabledWithSpacing: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      pointerEvents: "none",
      opacity: 0.15,
    },
    bottomPadded: {
      paddingBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  })
);
```

My component is like this:

```
export function SingleEmailCampaign() {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState<disabledSections>({
    to: false,
    from_email: false,
    subject: false,
    content: false,
  });
  const classes = useStyles();
  const sections = ["to", "from_email", "subject", "content"];
  const disableSections = (sectionName: String) => {
    var new_mapping: disabledSections = disabled;
    for (let section of sections) {
      new_mapping[section] = section === sectionName ? false : true;
    }
    setDisabled(new_mapping);
    console.log(disabled);
  };
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.container}>
      <AppBar position="static" className={classes.transparentAppBar}>
        <Toolbar className={classes.containerTopPadded}>
          <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h4" noWrap>
            Let's get started
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.appBarEnd}>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              variant="outlined"
              className={classes.button}
            >
              Schedule
            </Button>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              variant="outlined"
              className={classes.button}
            >
              Send
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Grid container spacing={6} className={classes.containerTopPadded}>
        <Grid item xs={12} lg={12}>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h4">
            {campaign?.name}
          </Typography>
          <Button>Edit Name</Button>
          <Box
            border={1}
            className={
              disabled.to ? classes.disabledWithSpacing : classes.spacing
            }
          >
            Sample To
          </Box>
          <Box
            border={1}
            className={
              disabled.from_email
                ? classes.disabledWithSpacing
                : classes.spacing
            }
          >
            Sample From
          </Box>
          <Box
            border={1}
            className={
              disabled.subject ? classes.disabledWithSpacing : classes.spacing
            }
          >
          </Box>
            Sample Subject
          <Box
            border={1}
            className={
              disabled.content ? classes.disabledWithSpacing : classes.spacing
            }
          >
            Sample Content
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

My expectation is that the sections other than the one clicked should get disabled, the state is being updated correctly but the sections are not getting disabled. Any suggestions would really help.

Comment: Did you try to remove `createStyles` and just return the styles object instead?

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Comment: It works when I somehow trigger a hot reload, then it starts disabling other sections

Comment: There must be something wrong with the way you update the state. Did you try logging the new state value upon clicking the button? Was the new state different from the previous state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the way you are trying to copy the state. You cannot/shouldn't mutate the current state. When you use:

```
 var new_mapping: disabledSections = disabled;
```

You are mutating the original state. What you need to do is perform a shallow merge. I would just use the spread operator on it. Change

```
 var new_mapping: disabledSections = disabled;
```

should be

```
  var new_mapping: disabledSections =  {...disabled}
```

Example: (not typescript)

```
  const disableSections = (value) => {
    let new_mapping = { ...disabled };
    for (let section of sections) {
      new_mapping[section] = section === value ? false : true;
    }
    setDisabled(new_mapping);
  };
```

sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sunset-7kn0w?file=/src/App.js